# Weird sound at the end of unforgiven II

Tags: sound, metallica

At the last part of Metallica - Unforgiven II (5:46-5:49) there is a weird 'bubble-like' sound. it also sounds like some skype notification to me.

does anybody know what makes this sound? as far as I know, none of the rock instruments produces a sound like that.

(I checked many official releases of the song and they all have it)

https://youtu.be/G-Bn_kD6QN4?t=346

Comment: Can it be the guitarist's fingers sliding on the strings?

Comment: I don't think we are talking about the same sound. I have heard sliding many times with both slider on/off but they don't produce a weird sound like that

Comment: yes I know, it sounds like when you change volume in a mac computer.

Comment: @Bebs YES! exactly!

Comment: It sounds like the combination of fingers sliding on strings through a wah wah pedal